# sh: 1: tailwind: not found when run npm start

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Hi I configured tailwind css with react but keep getting error when I run npm start sh: 1: tailwind: not found

> demo@0.1.0 start /home/tarek/Documents/Tong/tripcanvas-assesment
>   npm run tailwind:css && react-scripts start
>
> demo@0.1.0 tailwind:css /home/tarek/Documents/Tong/tripcanvas-assesment
>   tailwind build src/css/tailwind.src.css -c  tailwind.js -o src/css/tailwind.css
>
> ```
> sh: 1: tailwind: not found
> npm ERR! file sh
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
> npm ERR! demo@0.1.0 tailwind:css: `tailwind build src/css/tailwind.src.css -c  tailwind.js -o src/css/tailwind.css`
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the demo@0.1.0 tailwind:css script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/tarek/.npm/_logs/2019-07-26T06_27_45_711Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! demo@0.1.0 start: `npm run tailwind:css && react-scripts start`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the demo@0.1.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/tarek/.npm/_logs/2019-07-26T06_27_45_757Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Give us some more code to work with doc.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show us your package.json?

Have you installed scripts at all? `npm` or `yarn`